# tellp() after seekp() in ate mode

Tags: c++11, file-handling

I was looking at seekp and tellp() functionality. In below code, tellp() returns -1 after f2.seekp(10). I could not understand why -1 is returned. This I tested in both compilers (Visual Studio as well as TDM GCC 4.9.2 64 bit) and results are consistent. There is also another post similar to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48393195/whether-tellp-not-defined-in-append-mode/48393810#48393810) and in that case issue seems to be with the compiler and visual studio returns correct results. I raised separate post because issues are different.

```
/** Open in ate mode. ios::in is used to ensure that file is not destroyed. */
    ofstream f2("h2.txt", ios::ate | ios::out | ios::in);
    if (!f2)   //0 means error. You can also use f1.fail()
    {
        // open failed
        cerr << "cannot open the file\n";
        exit(-1);
    }
    ios::pos_type currentPos = f2.tellp();
    cout << "Initial Write Pointer Position = " << currentPos << endl;
    // Write some data. It should be written at the end.
    f2 << 20;
    currentPos = f2.tellp();
    cout << "Write Pointer Position after write = " << currentPos << endl;

    // Seek to specific position. File pointer must change accordingly.
    f2.seekp(10);
    currentPos = f1.tellp();
    cout << "Write Pointer Position after seek = " << currentPos << endl;

    // Write some data
    f2 << "ABC";
    currentPos = f2.tellp();
    cout << "Final Write Pointer seek and write = " << currentPos << endl;
    f2.close();
```

Edit:
Here is the complete code. There was a mistake in the code and that is why result was incorrect. There is no issue with seekp() in ate mode.

```
int main()
{
    string file_name;
    int currentPos;
   cout<<"Enter the file name";
    getline(cin,file_name);

    fstream f2(file_name, ios::ate | ios::out | ios::in);
    if (!f2)   //0 means error. You can also use f1.fail()
    {
        // open failed
        cerr << "cannot open the file\n";
    }
    else
    {
        currentPos = f2.tellp();
        cout << "Initial Write Pointer Position = " << currentPos << endl;
        // Write some data. It should be written at the end.
        f2 << 20;
        currentPos = f2.tellp();
        cout << "Write Pointer Position after write = " << currentPos << endl;

        // Seek to specific position. File pointer must change accordingly.
        f2.seekp(10);
        currentPos = f2.tellp();
        cout << "Write Pointer Position after seek = " << currentPos << endl;

        // Write some data
        f2 << "ABC";
        currentPos = f2.tellp();
        cout << "Final Write Pointer seek and write = " << currentPos << endl;
        f2.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Variable `f1` is not declared. Please replace the posted code with a [mcve]

Comment: You solved my problem. I had copy paste problem from previous code and after correcting it worked and updated code is posted in original post. It was compiling in my case because I had other part of the code as well